# Optimize a single record select query in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very simple SQL query that I want to optimize:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE email = 'jon@gmail.com'
```

I just want to get the 1 record that matches this user's email.

Is there anything I can do to make this query faster, aside from adding an index on the email column?

Does adding "Limit 1" make it faster?

What about doing `ORDER BY email DESC` since "j" is early in the alphabet?

Comment: Adding an index is the only option. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: Just wondering what else can be done.

Comment: Adding LIMIT 1 will be faster, since it will stop the full table scan early, if record id found. However, it will be same speed if `jon@gmail.com` is not found. It also won't return all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an index on the column `email`. There is no other way to make it fast.

The exact syntax depends on your database engine. If you email is unique (which is common with users table), then make an index unique too.

Comment: Thanks quarterdome, I'm already aware of adding indices as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to adding an index, you could find out something about 'john@gmail.com' that is already indexed. Perhaps you have a UserID, AccountID, etc?

If this is going to be for a "production" sort of query, searching on a non-indexed varchar field is going to be painful no matter how you try to optimize.

Comment: I only have their email for the lookup.